# What's wrong with this argument that parity is always conserved?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, parity

Here's a simple argument that every scalar field theory is parity symmetric.

- Consider the group $G = O(3, 1) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^4$ of improper Lorentz transformations $\Lambda$ and spacetime translations by $a^\mu$. Denote the element of this group comprised of $\Lambda$ followed by $a^\mu$ by $(\Lambda, a^\mu)$.
- In quantum mechanics, a group $G$ of physical transformations is represented on our Hilbert space by some unitary representation $R$. I'm not assuming any symmetry here; it's just that *something* has to happen when we boost, translate, etc. our system, and that must be represented by operators $R[(\Lambda, a^\mu)]$. For example, every system carries a (possibly projective) $SO(3)$ representation whether it's rotationally symmetric or not, just because you *can* rotate it.
- Parity is defined as $(P, 0)$, and by definition the parity operator is
  $$\hat{P} = R[(P, 0)].$$
- Time translation is defined as $(I, e_t)$ and by definition the time translation operator is
  $$\hat{U} = R[(I, e_t)].$$
  The Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ is by definition proportional to $\log \hat{U}$, e.g. as in the [Wightman axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms).
- To avoid the complications of projective representations, we consider a theory with only scalar fields. We know that $(P, 0)$ and $(I, e_t)$ commute. Using nothing but the definition of a representation, $R(g) R(g') = R(gg')$, it's straightforward to show that $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{H}$ commute.

Clearly I'm doing something physically wrong, because there are scalar field theories that break parity. Exactly what step is invalid?

Comment: What is wrong is the existence of the unitary representation of the whole $O(3,1) \times \mathbb R^4$. When a quantum physical system breaks parity, this just means that the representation which exists is only of   $SO(3,1) \times \mathbb R^4$.   Existence of the whole representation is decided by Nature not by our mathematical models.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I think this what's really confusing me. As a simpler example, there are plenty of systems that are not rotationally invariant, but their Hilbert spaces still carry a representation of $SU(2)$, corresponding to the physical act of rotating the system. (i.e. something has to actually happen when you pick it up and spin it!) Right? So why doesn't everything have to carry an $O(3, 1) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^4$ representation because we can boost, reflect, rotate, translate, etc. everything?

Comment: @ValterMoretti Moreover, I thought the parity operator was _defined_ to be $R[(P, 0)]$. If it's not defined as that, then what even is it?

Comment: It seems to me that you are confound  here dynamical symmetries and symmetries. If a potential has the form $U(x,y,z,) = x^2+y^2+ 3z^2$ the corresponding Hamiltonian is not invariant under rotation, even if there is the standard representation $(U_R\psi)(x) = \psi(R^{-1}x)$.

Comment: You may have different notions of symmetry breaking. You may have a representation of a symmetry at the level of algebra of observables, but there is no unitary implementation of it. Or there is but dynamics is not invariant. Finally you may have a unitary implementation but no invariant state...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I think I’m doing something different from what you’re saying. I don’t postulate these symmetries commute with the Hamiltonian! Instead I define the Hamiltonian as the operator that represents time translation in the group, and infer that parity commutes with it using the group multiplication law.

Comment: So the Hamiltonian you obtain this way is not the physical one, if parity symmetry is broken...

Comment: @ValterMoretti But is the Hamiltonian not just the generator of time translations? How can $e^{-iHt}$ be anything besides $R(\text{time translation})$? (I completely agree with you something has to be wrong here, it's just that every step of the argument feels totally natural to me.)

Comment: Please give me an explicit  example of theory where there is the problem you mention. An example of a theory along my point of view is a massless fermion  field described by a Weyl (quantized) 2-spinor field. In that case only the orthochronous Poincare' group can be unitarily represented. Parity does not exist.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Well, the argument is supposed to apply to _any_ theory. But explicitly maybe consider $\mathcal{L} = (\partial \phi)^2/2 + \phi^3$ where $\phi$ is a pseudoscalar.

Comment: If it is pseudoscalar there is an action of parity. Do you mean that the Lagrangian is not invariant? However here $\phi^3$ has to be renormalized.

Comment: In your case, formally (up to renormalisation) you can define the stress energy tensor operator and thus the total momentum,angular momentum and boost, integrating it. Exponentiating these generators you have a unitary representation of the orthochronous Poincaré group. Next you look for a unitary operator such that $U\phi(x) U^\dagger = - \phi(Px)$.

Comment: As there is the self-interaction potential, you cannot quantize in terms of $a_k$ and $a^\dagger_k$. Asymptotically you can, working in the formal Dirac picture. However, if this operator exists it does not leave invariant the total Hamiltonian, due to  $\phi^3$. *So parity symmetry is not a dynamical symmetry.* And it was one of my options above.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Okay, I think the difference is, you are constructing these operators explicitly. But my argument is that these operators _must_ exist on physical grounds. (e.g. I know that rotation operators exist for a single particle, even if I don't have an explicit form for them, because rotations are an actual, physical action one can do) Is that not valid?

Comment: Basic axioms just requires the existence of a unitary representation of orthochronous Poincaré group. The rest has to be investigated case by case, unless remarkable general results as PCT theorem.

Comment: In your case, with $\phi^3$, the notion of *particle* is forbidden. It exists only asymptotically. In that regime you can define a complete rep of Poincaré group by statndard canonical quantization with the option that $\phi$ is pseudo scalar. When you try to use this representation perturbatively you immediately see that the found $U_P$ is not a symmetry of the complete theory because it does not commute with the interaction Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take issue with the part where you write: "*something* has to happen when we boost, translate, etc. our system, and that must be represented by operators..."

**Parity can transform a physical configuration of matter into a nonsense, physically-impossible configuration of matter.** For example, it maps real left-handed neutrinos into impossible right-handed neutrinos.

In other words, P is not guaranteed to be an automorphism of the Hilbert space of our universe. It is a morphism, but not an automorphism. It maps part of the Hilbert space into nonsense configurations that are not part of the Hilbert space of our universe.